# Twig - 2 Input fields - Second input field should change depending on the first input

Tags: jquery, html, twig

I have 2 Input fields.
The first one has some Dropdown choices.
The second one has also some choices but it changes the choices depending on the first input.

**First input:**

```
<select name="des" id="des" class="selectpicker form-control">
    <option selected disabled> -- </option>
    {% for dep in department %}
       <option>{{ dep.description }}</option> 
    {% endfor %}  
</select>
```

**Idea #1:**
It thought something about `{% set value = "value of first input" %}` and catch it with if-else. 
The second input could start like this:

```
<select name="des-spz" id="des-spz"
  {% for dep in department %}
    {% if dep.fid == value %}
      <option>{{ dep.description }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

But I don't know how to set the value.

**Idea #2:**
I also thought something about catching the input value via jquery and append the options
**like:**

```
$('#des').on('change', function()  {
  if($('#des').val() == 'Anwendungssupport'){
    $('.des-spz').append(
      '<option >Cloud</option>'
    );
});
```

But the append do not work and it is actually really tough to write every possible dropdown option instead of cycling through with twig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have the solution:

I just needed to cycle around the jquery paragraph:

**Solution:**
**A seperate Jquery for the " -- " option**
cause you don't cycle through the " -- " option.

```
$('#des').on('change', function()  {
  if($('#des').val() == 'Anwendungssupport'){
    $("#des-spz").empty().append(
      '<option value="--"> -- </option>'
    );
    $('#des-spz').selectpicker('refresh');
  }
});
```

And then just cycle through the rest of the options you want:

```
{% for dep in department %}
  {% for i in 1..12 %}
  {% set numb = '10000' ~ i %}
    {% if dep.fid == numb  %}
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#des').on('change', function()  {
        if($('#des').val() == 'Anwendungssupport'){
          $("#des-spz").append(
            '<option value="{{ dep.description }}">{{ dep.description }}</option>' 
          );
          $('#des-spz').selectpicker('refresh');

        } 
    });
  });
  </script>
{% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Don't forget to refresh the selectpicker ;)
Bye, 'til next time!

Answer (score 0):

As always after posting a problem I find a solution myself...

A solution for the **Idea #2:**

```
$('#bereichdes').on('change', function()  {
  if($('#des').val() == 'Anwendungssupport'){
    $("#des-spz").empty().append(
      '<option value="--"> -- </option>' +
      '<option value="cloud">Cloud</option>'
    );
    $('#des-spz').selectpicker('refresh');

  } else if($('#des').val() == 'Gerätesupport') {
    $("#des-spz").empty().append(
      '<option value="--"> -- </option>' +
      '<option value="bildschirm">Bildschirm</option>'
    );
    $('#des-spz').selectpicker('refresh');
  }
});
```

2 Things: 
1. After appending an option the selectpicker needs to be refreshed.
2. After selecting another value in the first input the options in the second input needs to be cleared with `.empty()`

But it's still hard to write all by hand instead of cycling through..